# On sums and mixtures

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Suppose that we have a sum, involving several terms.
Then, each term which participates in this sum is called a 'summand'.

Now, suppose that instead we have a mixture of entities.
Is there a word to describe an individual entity participating in the mixture?
Say, something like 'mixand'?

Comment: It's an *ingredient*.

Comment: By "a mixture of entities" do you mean someting like y=x+(ab)+sin(theta)+sqrt(25/9.26)?

Comment: ... a component

Comment: Please provide a sentence where you would use the word so we can get the right one, there are many candidates.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Oh, component does seem like the correct term. Thanks you!